# C preprocessor Macro defining Macro

Tags: gcc, c-preprocessor

Can you do something like this with a macro in **C**?

```
#define SUPERMACRO(X,Y) #define X Y

then

SUPERMACRO(A,B) expands to #define A B
```

I have a feeling not because the preprocessor only does one pass.

Official gcc only. No third-party tools please.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Macros can't expand into preprocessing directives.  From C99 6.10.3.4/3 "Rescanning and further replacement":

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles one,

Answer (score 20):

You cannot define macros in other macros, but you can call a macro from your macro, which can get you essentially the same results.

```
#define B(x) do {printf("%d", (x)) }while(0)
#define A(x) B(x)
```

so, `A(y)` is expanded to `do {printf("%d", (y)) }while(0)`

Answer (score 4):

No.  The order of operations is such that all preprocessor directives are recognized before any macro expansion is done; thus, if a macro expands into something that looks like a preprocessor directive, it won't be recognized as such, but will rather be interpreted as (erroneous) C source text.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, you cannot. You can call other macros in macros but not define new ones.

Comment: how about if you did 2 passes of the pre processor

Comment: The syntax is not valid. # is kind of a reserved character in macros. # must be followed by a macro parameter to be valid. This will 'stringify' the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running it through with only the preprocess option, then compiling with the preprocessed file.

Answer (score -1):

You might do this though:
#define SUPERMACRO(X,Y) define X Y

Then you can use your editors macro-expansion functionality and paste in the missing #.

Or even better: Use a different, more powerful string-processing language as your preprocessor.