# Macros that define macros

Tags: macros, c-preprocessor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C, Macro defining Macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2429240/c-macro-defining-macro)

Does anyone know how to pull off something like this...

I have a lot of repetitive macros as : -

```
#define MYMACRO1(x)         Do1(x)
#define MYMACRO2(x,y)       Do2(x, y)
#define MYNEXTMACRO1(x)     Do1(x)
#define MYNEXTMACRO2(x,y)   Do2(x, y)
```

The code above works fine, but I want to write a macro that creates macros (a meta macro).

For example: -

```
#define MYMETAMACRO(name) \
#define #name1(x)     Do1(x) \
#define #name2(x,y)   Do2(x, y) \
```

Such that I can do : -

```
MYMETAMACRO(MYMACRO);
MYMETAMACRO(MYNEXTMACRO);
```

and then : -

```
MYMACRO1(2);
MYMACRO2(2,3);
MYNEXTMACRO1(4);
MYNEXTMACRO2(4, 5);
```

The preprocessor bombs out at the `#define` as it thinks it is a missing parameter of the macro.

Comment: doesn't working with the c preprocessor just make you yearn for lisp?

Comment: The answers to the other question may be technically correct, but I don't think they are as complete as they could be, so I won't vote to close.

Comment: @Whirlwind: You *could* always add a new, more complete answer to the other question...

Comment: sth I could, but David brought it to my attention that it was incomplete.  However, I have added my answer there, for future reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't write a macros that writes another macros in C/C++.

I've spent enough time trying to do something like that using C preprocessor in C++ in the past, asked people around, and concluded that it isn't possible.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot define macros in other macros, but you can call a macro from your macro, which can get you essentially the same results.

```
#define B(x) do {printf("%d", (x)) }while(0)
#define A(x) B(x)
```

so, `A(y)` is expanded to `do {printf("%d", (y)) }while(0)`