# Macro within macro does not work

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I came across one more piece of code that is even more confusing..

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define f(a,b) a##b

#define g(a) #a

#define h(a) g(a)

int main(void)
{
    printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2)));
    printf("%s\n",g(1));
    printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));
    return 0;
}
```

output is

```
12

1

f(1,2)
```

My assumption was
1) first `f(1,2)` is replaced by `12` , because of macro `f(a,b)`
concantenates its arguments
2) then `g(a)` macro replaces `1` by a string literal `"1"`
3) the output should be `1`

But why is `g(f(1,2))` not getting substituted to `12`.
I'm sure i'm missing something here.
Can someone explain me this program ?

Comment: because g is evaluated before f, which converts `f(1,2)` to a string literal.

Comment: You say C in the title (which you don't need to), but tag C++? Probably not different for this, but you should be consistent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Macro replacement occurs from the outside in. (Strictly speaking, the preprocessor is required to behave as though it replaces macros one at a time, starting from the beginning of the file and restarting after each replacement.)

The standard (C99 §6.10.3.2/2) says

> If, in the replacement list, a parameter is immediately preceded by a `#` preprocessing
>   token, both are replaced by a single character string literal preprocessing token that
>   contains the spelling of the preprocessing token sequence for the corresponding
>   argument.

Since `#` is present in the *replacement list* for the macro `g`, the argument `f(1,2)` is converted to a string immediately, and the result is `"f(1,2)"`.

On the other hand, in `h(f(1,2))`, since the replacement list doesn't contain `#`, §6.10.3.1/1 applies,

> After the arguments for the invocation of a function-like macro have been identified,
>    argument substitution takes place. A parameter in the replacement list, unless preceded
>   by a `#` or `##` preprocessing token or followed by a `##` preprocessing token (see below), is
>   replaced by the corresponding argument after all macros contained therein have been
>   expanded.

and the argument `f(1, 2)` is macro expanded to give `12`, so the result is `g(12)` which then becomes `"12"` when the file is "re-scanned".

Answer (score 1):

Macros can't expand into preprocessing directives. From C99 6.10.3.4/3 "Rescanning and further replacement":

> The resulting completely macro-replaced preprocessing token sequence
>   is not processed as a preprocessing directive even if it resembles
>   one,

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2429368/2591612

But you can call `f(a,b)` from `g` like you did with `h`. `f(a,b)` is interpreted as a string literal as [@Red Alert](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2817371/red-alert) states.